# How would I pass a string so the notification actually has the reminder message?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, alarmmanager

Making basic reminder app. Can't figure out how to pass the actually reminder text so the notification actually displays the reminder instead of just having a blank notification.

**In MainActivity, where alarm created**

```
private fun startAlarm (cal : Calendar) {
        val alarmManager: AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val intent :Intent = Intent(this, AlertReceiver().javaClass)
        val pendingIntent : PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqCode, intent, 0)

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
}
```

**AlertReceiver**

```
class AlertReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val notificationObj : Notification = Notification(context)
        val notif : NotificationCompat.Builder = notificationObj.createNotification("")

        notificationObj.getManager().notify(1, notif.build())
    }

}
```

**Notification, createNotification**

```
    fun createNotification(reminder: String): NotificationCompat.Builder{
        //to load main screen when click notification
        val main: Intent = Intent (this, MainActivity().javaClass).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingMain: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, main, 0)
        val notif : NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Reminder:")
            .setContentText(reminder)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingMain)
            .setAutoCancel((true))

        return notif
    }
```

Comment: You already have `setContentText(reminder)` but you are passing reminder as an empty string in your `notificationObj.createNotification("")` call. Do you get a blank notification even if you pass some non-empty string?

Comment: Yea that was just a temporary placeholder. I can't figure out a way to pass the string containing the reminder to the alert receiver class from my MainActivity @shriakhilc